# Changing xml-mapping from the user entity (SonataUserBundle) to annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

I've implemented the SonataAdmin and SonataUserBundle into my project. 
With this I've created the Application\Sonata\UserBundle which has a User entity. This entity uses xml-mapping for Doctrine. I'm wondering if it's possible to change this configuration to annotations as I'm using annotations in the rest of my project.

Thx.

Comment: Please also see this solution which works fine for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042010/annotations-in-extended-sonata-user-class-not-being-read

Answer (score 1):

```
sonata.user.admin.user:
      class: %sonata.user.admin.user.class%
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Usuarios, label: Usuarios }
      arguments: [null, %sonata.user.admin.user.entity%, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
      calls:
        - [ setUserManager, [fos_user.user_manager]]
```

where `sonata.user.admin.user.class` and `.entity` are values set in your config file.

You should probably change your `fos_user.user_manager` also but i don't know what you use...