# Extending the User entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to extend the User Entity of the sonata user bundle, but it always fails (at least when I want to use ist with the sonata admin bundle). If I use the Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User Entity it works and I can edit it in the dashboard.

My Entity looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
}
```

In my config.yml I defined the following options:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     MyNamespace\MyBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
    user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

And:

```
sonata_user:
security_acl: true
manager_type: orm
class:
   user: MyNamespace\MyBundle\Entity\User
```

The login is working correctly, but then I get the error message

"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_sonata_user_user_create" as such route does not exist.") in SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig at line 39."

My routing.yml looks like this:

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /

_sonata_admin:
    host:       www.mydomain.com
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /
    schemes:    [https]
```

Even if I follow this tutorial ([Extending Sonata User Bundle and adding new fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621993/extending-sonata-user-bundle-and-adding-new-fields/15625000#15625000)) step by step I get the same error.

Comment: Can  execute:
`php app/console router:debug | grep admin_sonata_user_user_create`

Comment: Yes, there's no result, because the route is missing completely. If I switch back to the default sonata-user-bundle User-Entity, the route is working again and appears in the router:debug output.

Comment: Why don't You extend SonataUser instead of FOSUserBundle Entity ? I just guess, that sonata extends FOS User ? YOu can't ommit SonataUser Entity if you are using this bundle.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I thought this would be the correct way if I use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

Comment: I haven't use this bundle for some time, but i remember that it was tricky :-| I don't want to show you "bad way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User`  is extended `Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User` so why not just to make changes there instead of another class?

It's already extended bundle so you can make all the changes there. I put my additional fields there.

My file Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User.php is like:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $company;
```

If your really want to use another class you need to take care about routing.

Check `\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\config\admin_orm.xml` - it's the place where original class is added as a service.

You can see there **%sonata.user.admin.user.entity%** parameter - you could change this in config if you want to change to another class. I think it's better than changing fos_user.user_class.

You can also move the whole file to your `Application/Sonata/UserBudle` but then you need to load it inside `DependencyInjection/ApplicationSonataUserExtension.php`

Btw, this is really tricky in Sonata which user bundles as Paweł wrote and takes a lot of debugging to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this finally worked for me. I additionally had to delete the Resources/config/doctrine Folder to be able to use annotations and doctrine:generate:entities (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042010/annotations-in-extended-sonata-user-class-not-being-read)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to write about removing folder - sorry for that. Glad you managed to make it work for you :)